# Why is minify js / css page speed and yslow different?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, google-pagespeed

I I check my performance web on the pagespeed tab, the result like this  :

[image]

If I check on the yslow tab, the result like this :

[image]

Why is minify js / css page speed and yslow different?

The message like this :

```
There are 9 components that can be minified

inline <style> tag #2
inline <style> tag #4
inline <script> tag #2
inline <script> tag #4
inline <script> tag #6
inline <script> tag #7
inline <script> tag #8
inline <script> tag #9
inline <script> tag #10
```

And how do I find out which css and js need to be minified?

Note : I using gtmetrix to check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PageSpeed` shows that you have minify your `js` and `css`

`Yslow` showing that you have `inline` `style` and `script` on multiple page which can be add in to the external file and then minify for `pagespeed` improvement.

Comment: I'm still confused. What do you mean by external file?

Comment: if you have page leave css or js please add those in to external file like style.css and script.js instead of page leavel.

Comment: So you mean all css files are combined into 1 css file and all js files are combined into 1 js file? Like that?

Comment: yes but page speed shows you already did that but still there is more inline css and Js on few of the pages.

Comment: Can I find out the name of the cs and js file that needs to be minified?

Comment: GTmatrix don't do that its really difficult.

Comment: It makes me have to look for it

Comment: It's no problem

Comment: What is meant by `tag #2`?